# Render RGB-D image from mesh

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, rendering, vtk

I have a mesh model (.ply file) and I have rendered it with VTK and changed the camera viewpoint.

From the new camera viewpoint how can I render an RGB and a depth image? I think this might be raytracing, but not sure

**EDIT**

I want to generate a real depth map, as opposed to just a visualization of the depth. The visualization can be achieved by using values in Z buffer and scaling between 0-255 but this does not provide real depth information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the real world depth from the camera I have done the following:

```
double z = render_win->GetZbufferDataAtPoint(x,y);
worldPicker->Pick(x, y, z, renderer);
worldPicker->GetPickPosition(coords);
double euclidean_distance = sqrt(pow((coords[0] - cam_pos[0]), 2) + pow(coords[1] - cam_pos[1], 2) + pow(coords[2] - cam_pos[2], 2));
```

where `cam_pos` is the camera position in real world coordinates. This seems to do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short few lines if you already have the application set up and rendering, this has to be after the mesh has rendered at least once

```
// Screenshot  
vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter> windowToImageFilter = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter>::New();
windowToImageFilter->SetInput(renderWindow);
windowToImageFilter->SetMagnification(3); //set the resolution of the output image (3     times the current resolution of vtk render window)
windowToImageFilter->SetInputBufferTypeToRGBA(); //also record the alpha (transparency)   channel
windowToImageFilter->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter> writer = 
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter>::New();
writer->SetFileName("screenshot2.png");
writer->SetInputConnection(windowToImageFilter->GetOutputPort());
writer->Write();
```

This is from the [VTK Public Wiki](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/Screenshot)

Comment: this will only render the RGB image, what about depth?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve RGB image you can use `vtkWindowToImageFilter` class, allowing to read data from the vtkWindow.
For the Depth Image, i tried a solution which is to modify color on the mesh using `vtkDepthSortPolyData` , and again, read from the window.

See the example above :

```
# define VTK_CREATE(type, nom) vtkSmartPointer<type> nom = vtkSmartPointer<type>::New()
int main ()
   {
      VTK_CREATE(vtkPLYReader, reader);
      reader->SetFileName ("mesh.ply");
      reader->Update ();

      // create depth sort algo
      VTK_CREATE(vtkDepthSortPolyData, sort);
      sort->SetInput(reader->GetOutput ());

      // init stuff for rendering
      VTK_CREATE(vtkPolyDataMapper, mapper);
      VTK_CREATE(vtkActor, actor);
      VTK_CREATE(vtkRenderer, rend);
      VTK_CREATE(vtkRenderWindow, rw);
      VTK_CREATE(vtkRenderWindowInteractor, inte);

      VTK_CREATE(vtkCamera, cam);
      sort->SetDirectionToBackToFront (); // camera direction
      sort->SetCamera (cam); // set camera or runtime warning
      sort->SortScalarsOn ();
      sort->Update ();

      mapper->SetScalarVisibility(true);

      // limit max scalar (nb Color)
      mapper->SetScalarRange (0, sort->GetOutput ()->GetNumberOfCells ());
      mapper->SetInputConnection(sort->GetOutputPort ());
      mapper->Update ();

      actor->SetMapper(mapper);
      actor->RotateY (59); // transform with a rotation to see depth
      actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1, 0, 0);
      sort->SetProp3D (actor); // set the actor to the algo

      rend->SetActiveCamera (cam);
      rw->AddRenderer(rend);
      rend->AddActor(actor);
      inte->SetRenderWindow (rw);

      inte->Initialize ();

      // read depth image from vtk Window
      VTK_CREATE (vtkWindowToImageFilter, screen);
      screen->SetInput (rw);
      screen->Update ();
      // start rendering for visualization
      rw->Render ();

      // save the depth img as a png
      VTK_CREATE(vtkPNGWriter, writer);
      writer->SetFileName ("output.png");
      writer->SetInputConnection (screen->GetOutputPort ());
      writer->Write ();

      inte->Start ();
      return 0;
    }
```

Tested on VTK 5.10.

Comment: This will only visualize the depth as opposed to give real depth values